# Invalid Procedure Call or Argument when passing Excel.Range from VBA to C# Library

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I have a C# Class Library project in Visual Studio that I am using to extend the functionality of a VBA project.

I have made a COM accessible class that creates a TLB file on build; my VBA project references this TLB file.

I want to be able to pass an Excel.Range object from VBA to my C# class; however I keep receiving the **'Invalid Procedure Call or Argument'** error and I don't understand why.

C# Method:

```
public void SetMetrics(Excel.Range MetricRange)
{
    //Implementation
}
```

VBA Code:

```
ObjectName.SetMetrics (SheetName.Range("RangeName"))
```

***Test Outcomes:***

- If I create an alternative method with no parameters or alternative types such as int, bool etc - it works fine. The error only seems to occur when I try to pass a Range.
- If I make the VBA return a value form the method (see below), it works - *even though the method is explicitly defined with void.*

FunctionName = ClassName.SetMetrics (SheetName.Range("RangeName"))

- If I have more than one Excel.Range parameter - VBA forces me to return a value even if I do not want too; but this also works.

I don't understand why I have these limitations - why do I have to return a value when passing objects to my library?

Comment: Did you try `Dim rng as Range` then `Set rng = Range("RangeName")` and then `SetMetrics(rng)`? How do you know that the VBA compiler treats `SheetName.Range("namedRange")` as Range type not Variant or 2d array? C# requires the types to match exactly and it seems youre not making sure the type is actually a Range.

Comment: Remove the parentheses in the VBA, or use Call: `Call ObjectName.SetMetrics(SheetName.Range("RangeName"))` or `ObjectName.SetMetrics SheetName.Range("RangeName")`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Rory - it was a VBA Syntax error:

Answer: "Remove the parentheses in the VBA, or use Call: Call"

Thank you for resolving this so quickly!

Best